# how to remove title in img html

Tags: html, image

i have a html text like that i get from database, but it have a hover that show the image name, so i want to remove the title

from this

```html
<img title="AAAAAAA" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg" alt="" width="212" height="212">
```

to this

```html
<img title="" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg" alt="" width="212" height="212">
```

i have tried

```html
var text = '<img title="AAAAAAA" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg" alt="" width="212" height="212">'

text.replace(/(<img .*title=")(.+)(")/, '$1$3')
```

but it also remove my src
"<img title="">"

any help guys ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use JS function removeAttribute():

```js
document.getElementById("someId").removeAttribute("title");
console.log(document.getElementById("someId"));
```

```html
<img title="AAAAAAA" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg" alt="" width="212" height="212" id="someId">
```

EDIT: **How to remove with regex**

```js
var text = '<img title="AAAAAAA" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg" alt="" width="212" height="212">';



console.log(text.replace(/ title=".[^"]*"/, ''))
```

**How to remove only title´s value:**

```js
var text = '<img title="AAAAAAA" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg" alt="" width="212" height="212">';



console.log(text.replace(/title=".[^"]*"/, 'title=""'))
```

Comment: it doesnt have id sir , because i got the whole img text from database

Comment: OK, I will change it :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be very hard, if not impossible, to reliably parse HTML using the likes of regex, indexOf, etc. The whole issue can be totally avoided by using the built-in [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) object, as follows:

```js
const html = '<img title="AAAAAAA" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg" alt="" width="212" height="212">';
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
const img = doc.body.children[0];
img.title = "";
console.log(img.outerHTML)
```

You could also use `img.removeAttribute("title");` if you want to get totally rid of the `title` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only getting the element as a string and not as a DOM element, then you can try using `\"[\s\S]+(?= )` to select the portion of string that goes from the first " to the first space (returning you `"AAAAAAA"`).

You can then replace the text as per your code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler and cleaner way.

```
var xmlString = '<img title="AAAAAAA" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg" alt="" width="212" height="212">'

var x = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml").documentElement
x.removeAttribute("title")
console.log(x)
```